# Adding an object pointer to a vector of pointer-to-objects located inside a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, vector

I'm trying to dynamically allocate objects, then add those pointers to the object to a vector. However I get the error:
"conversion from 'Library (*)()' to non-scalar type 'Library' requested". How do I correct this?

I've included the files below

//Item class

```
class Item
    private:
        std::string idCode;
        std::string title;
    public:
        Item(std::string idc, std::string t)
        {
            this->idCode=idc;
            this->title=t;
        };
```

//Book Class inheriting from Item class

```
class Book: public Item   //class inherits from parent Item
{
private:
    std::string author;
public:
    //constructor
    Book(std::string idcIn,std::string tIn,std::string authorIn)
    :Item(idcIn, tIn)
    {    author=authorIn;}
};
```

//Library class which holds the vector of pointers to

```
class Library
    private:
        std::vector<Item*>holdings;
    public:
        void addLibraryItem(Item* item)
        {
            holdings.push_back(item);
        }
```

And here is the main file

```
void addItem(Library);  //prototype for adding Item function

int main()
{
    Library lib();  //create Library object

    addItem(lib);   //ERROR POINTS TO HERE

    return 0;
}

void addItem(Library lib)
{
    Item *ptr=new Book("bookID", "Title", "Author")
    lib.Library::addLibraryItem(ptr);
}
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Library lib();` is wrong. This statement declares a function `lib` which returns `Library` and takes no parameter

This should have been `Library lib;`

Answer (score 2):

you should change definition of function `addItem` to

```
void addItem(Library& lib)
{
    Item *ptr=new Book("bookID", "Title", "Author")
    lib.addLibraryItem(ptr);
}
```

to be able to call method `addLibraryItem` of your **referenced** object, not copy of it

Answer (score 1):

Change `Library lib()` to `Library lib`.

Comment: What does it mean when it will fall out of scope?